# SQL count records equal to 1 value and count and group the rest

Tags: mysql, sql, database, count, group-by

I am having trouble with a query I need to write. For some reason I cant seem to get anything to work. I know the solution is very simple but I just can't seem to think of it.

Lets say I have a table in my DB called "entrys" that looks like this:

```
ID  |  Item  |  value
------------------------------
1  |  item 1  |  3
2  |  item 1  |  4
3  |  item 1  |  3
4  |  item 2  |  3
5  |  item 3  |  3
6  |  item 1  |  3
7  |  item 1  |  3
8  |  item 1  |  3
9  |  item 4  |  3
10 |  item 4  |  6
```

I want to count the times item 1 occur where value = 3 and then group the other items together can provide a count for them that = 3 so for example the output for this table will be

```
  Item  |  Count
---------------------
Item 1  |  5
Other   |  3
```

As item 1 occurs 5 times the with the value of 3 and all other items that have the value of 3 are grouped together and displayed as other with a count of 3

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using a derived table where your items are named either `Item1` or `Other`. Then group the derived table by name and select the count.

```
SELECT
    Item,
    COUNT(*)
FROM (
  SELECT
    (CASE
        WHEN Item = 'item 1'
        THEN 'Item 1'
        ELSE 'Other'
    END) Item
  FROM items
  WHERE value = 3) t1
GROUP BY Item
```

Comment: This worked like a charm. Just needed to add where clause and gave the results I needed, Thanks for your help I was so close but it just slipped my mind.

Answer (score 2):

The key to the aggregation is a `case` statement.  Then you need to count the appropriate values as well.  In MySQL, you can do:

```
SELECT (CASE WHEN Item = 'item 1' THEN Item ELSE 'Other' END) AS Item, COUNT(*) AS `Count3`
FROM entrys e
WHERE value = 3
GROUP BY Item;
```

MySQL allows the use of column aliases in the `GROUP BY`.  If you want counts of everything *and* where value is 3, then you can do:

```
SELECT (CASE WHEN Item = 'item 1' THEN Item ELSE 'Other' END) AS Item,
       COUNT(*) as AllCount, SUM(value = 3) as Count3
FROM entrys e
GROUP BY Item;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT CASE Item WHEN 'item 1' THEN Item ELSE 'Other' END AS Item, COUNT(ID) AS `Count`
FROM entrys
GROUP BY CASE Item WHEN 'item 1' THEN Item ELSE 'Other' END
```